# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de llamar a un método en javascript? En este fragmento me muestra undefined

Tags: javascript

```js
class Handys{
    constructor(marca,color,peso,resolucion,ram){
        this.marca = marca;
        this.color = color;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.resolucion = resolucion;
        this.ram = ram; 
        this.encendido = false;
    }

    sehendieInformation(){
        return
        `
        Die Marke :<b>${this.marca}</b><br>
        color:<b>${this.color}</b><br>
        peso:<b>${this.peso}</b> Gramos <br>
        die Auflösung :<b>${this.resolucion}</b> Pixel<br>
        Ram : <b>${this.ram}</b> GB
        Res camara Externa : <b>${this.rescamrexterna} pixel</b>`       
    }  
}//cierre de la class

let HandyErste = new Handys("Samsung","Weiß",250, 150,"2GB");
let HandyZweite = new Handys("Huawei","Schwarz",230,180,"3GB");
let Handydreite = new Handys("Nokia","Gelb",180 ,230,"4GB");


document.write(`${HandyErste.sehendieInformation()}<br>`); 
document.write(`${HandyZweite.sehendieInformation()} <br>`);
```

Tengo este error en un fragmento de código. Creo los objetos y al intentar mostrar el contenido de un método utilizando un `document.write` me muestra por pantalla `undefined` si se supone que para llamar al método es objet.metodo.

Comment: En consola no me muestra error pero me señala un warning en el archivo html

Comment: Tengo sentimientos encontrados con esta pregunta... por un lado estamos en SOes y la pregunta está en español, pero el código está en alemán! Me hace gracia, puesto que estoy aprendiendo alemán jaja vaya casualidad. Quería comentarte que por convención los nombres de las variables se escriben en `camelCase` no `PascalCase`, es decir, la primera letra debe ir en minúscula exactamente igual que con los métodos y funciones. Solo las clases se escriben con la primera en mayúscula.

Comment: Hola ya encontre el error tenia casi un dia buscándolo y no lo veía jajjaa esta  ensehendieInformation(){
        return
        `  hay un espacio entre el return y el Backticks  , yo tambien estoy aprendiendo aleman y utilizo el codigo para ir practicando Deutsch ,     
Danke Benito

Comment: Si la respuesta te ayudó, por favor márcala como aceptada para que la pregunta quede cerrada. Es la manera correcta de agradecer y ayudar a que las preguntas y respuestas lleguen a más personas que pueden tener un problema similar (o igual). Kein problem, estamos para ayudar :)

Answer (score 3):

Tienes que recordar que en JS los `;` de final de línea no son obligatorios... pero los intro si que marcan el final de una línea si no hay algo que indique lo contrario (un paréntesis abierto, una llave, algún tipo de "bloque" de código). Ergo, en el momento en que pones algo así:

```
return
'va a devolver esto'
```

JS ejecutará tu return y nunca llegará a evaluar siquiera la línea de abajo, puesto que el return ya ha hecho que el flujo se rompa y salga del mismo, no llegando a devolver absolutamente nada (de ahí que te devuelva `undefined`!)
Solución? Abrir el comentario en la misma línea que escribes el return, luego ya puedes pulsar enter cuantas veces quieras hasta que cierres esa comilla! (obviamente esto dependerá del tipo de comilla, si no usas un backtick o tilde invertida ( ` ) , es decir, si usas `'` o `"` no puedes dejar la línea sin terminar, deberás cerrar la comilla en la misma línea y utilizar un `+` para concatenar múltiples líneas!)

Te lo dejo resumido en comentario dentro del código también. Un saludo.

```js
class Handys{
    constructor(marca,color,peso,resolucion,ram){
        this.marca = marca;
        this.color = color;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.resolucion = resolucion;
        this.ram = ram; 
        this.encendido = false;
    }

    sehendieInformation() {
        /* 
         * Tenías un problema en este return... si pones return y luego un salto de línea directamente
         * javascript interpreta que no vas a devolver nada, recuerda que en JS los ; finales no son obligatorios
         */
        return `
        Die Marke :<b>${this.marca}</b><br>
        color:<b>${this.color}</b><br>
        peso:<b>${this.peso}</b> Gramos <br>
        die Auflösung :<b>${this.resolucion}</b> Pixel<br>
        Ram : <b>${this.ram}</b> GB
        Res camara Externa : <b>${this.rescamrexterna} pixel</b>`       
    }  
}//cierre de la class

let HandyErste = new Handys("Samsung","Weiß",250, 150,"2GB");
let HandyZweite = new Handys("Huawei","Schwarz",230,180,"3GB");
let Handydreite = new Handys("Nokia","Gelb",180 ,230,"4GB");


document.write(`${HandyErste.sehendieInformation()}<br>`); 
document.write(`${HandyZweite.sehendieInformation()} <br>`);
```